# Passing strings to list and deleting them using shared preferences

Tags: android, linked-list, sharedpreferences

i wish to, in one activity, put strings in the sharedpreferences, so then, in another activity, i get those strings, put them in a array and display them sequentially. I managed to do this, but i don`t have any idea how can i delete one specified string when asked. These strings will just be scattered on the shared preferences,and i dont know how to keep track of them. I can pass this unique int id to each element. I tried to use LinkedList, but i cannot pass this kind of structure as a shared preferences. I did not managed to make Gson work also. Please help.

Method that gets the string and put on shared preferences:

```
public void makefavorites(String[] a, String[] b, int id)
{
    int idfinal = id%10;
    idfinal = idfinal+1;
    a[idfinal] = b[idfinal] +"\n" + "\n"+ a[idfinal]; 

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Favorites", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    int temp = prefs.getInt("favorites_size", 0);

    edit.putInt("favorites_size", temp+1);
        edit.putString("array_" + prefs.getInt("favorites_size", 0), a[idfinal]);
    edit.commit();

    refreshfavorites();


}
```

Method that gets those strings, put on array and display it:

```
public void refreshfavorites()
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Favorites", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //GETS THE ARRAY SIZE
    int size = prefs.getInt("favorites_size", 0);
    String[] array = new String[size];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        array[i] = prefs.getString("array_" + i, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `SharedPreferences.Editor#putStringSet()` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html?

Comment: but how this gonna help me to keep track of the elements?

Comment: Because you can then store a `Set<String>` within shared preferences. If you need to remove an element, you can call `Set#remove()` and then store the updated set.

Comment: im sorry. im newbie on programming. So, i have the string i want to remove and a ID that i can use to identify this string, but i dont know how. how can i, later, comming to this method, delete an specific string having just the string or this id as data? being that ,i dont know how to put this id togheter with the string

Comment: If you use a Set, then you can't use an ID. Do you need an ID? Are your strings unique?

Comment: yes, they are. i want to put those strings on shared preferences, and in the refresfavorites() method, i want to print at list with all strings(i already took care to not put a string twice). This works fine, but, i want also to delete an element, having the string as a parameter and the same ID. this is actually an favorites system, where i put strings on the favorites, and print them on the favorites screen.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#remove%28java.lang.String%29 Allows removing strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use **editor.remove** method to delete specific value from arraylist..

```
public void removeArray(String[] list)()
{
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPrefs.edit();

int size = list.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        editor.remove("favorites_size"+i);
    }
    editor.commit();
 }
```

i hope its useful to you..

Comment: thank you!! seeing your code i had the idea of checking if each element inside the if is the string i wanna delete, to  simply remove it! Thank you!